# Coloring data points with LabelingFunction included

Tags: color, labeling

I have a plot generated by:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data -> labels, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",  LabelingFunction -> Center]
```

and I want to color the data labels. ColorFunction would work if LabelingFunction was not included. Is there a way to change the color with LabelingFunction included?

If the code is:

```
SeedRandom[1234567];
data = RandomPoint[Cube[], 5];
ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Boxed -> False, 
 LabelingFunction -> Center]
```

Is there a way to just assign colors to the labels in the style they are in without the data points showing?

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomPoint[Cuboid[], 5];
labels = IntegerName /@ Range[5];

ListPointPlot3D[(List /@ data) -> labels, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 LabelingFunction -> (Style[#3[[2, 1]], 16, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Last@#, MinMax[data[[All, 3]]], {0, 1}]]] &), 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

**Update:** *"to assign colors to the labels in the style they are in **without the data points showing**"*:

```
labeleddata = MapThread[
   Labeled[#, Style[#2, 16, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Last@#, MinMax[data[[All, 3]]], {0, 1}]]], Center] &,
   {data, labels}];

ListPointPlot3D[labeleddata, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

If you *have to* use `LabelingFunction` you can do:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data -> labels, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Center] &@
     Style[#3[[3, 1]], 16, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Last@#, MinMax[data[[All, 3]]], {0, 1}]]] &)]
```

[image]